# Wordpress Bad Request Error 400

Tags: php, mysql, errors

Can someone get me out of this trouble? I have successfuly tested wordpress on xampp and works fine, however, on a dedicated I 'm getting an error 400 Bad request until I manually remove any .php extension from the URL and proceed to the next step.
The solutions found online(Clearing Browser cookies, clearing the DNS and removing the .htaccess) did not help me.
Any help will be highly appreciated
thanks!

Comment: What do you mean remove the PHP extensions from the URL? What do your URLs look like?

Comment: Can you find your web server's logs? Are there errors, either in the main log or in the separate PHP log if you have one?